# Accessing POST data from controller in CakePHP

Tags: json, cakephp-2.3

If this is the JSON data that is being POST-ed and sent to my controller.

```
{
  "email" : "xyz@something.com" ,

  "password" : "mypassword"

}
```

And I want to access the email and the password and assign them to separate variables in my controller `function login ()` how do I go about it?

should I do something like this ?

```
public function login( )
{
   $temp=$this->request->email ;

   $foo=$this->request->password;

  }
```

Please let me know how I can do it . Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You need to get your json object and decode it. If your json object is called `$jsonObject`, do the decoding like this 
`$data = json_decode($jsonObject, true); 
$temp= $data['email'];
$foo= data['password'];`